# Hide horizontal scroll bar but be able to scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #0090ff;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.invisible-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu invisible-scrollbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="news">Fashion</a>
  <a href="people">People</a>
  <a href="work">Work</a>
</div>
```

This hides the horizontal bar in Chrome and Explorer but did not on Firefox, please help.

Comment: Did you try `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll/16671476

Comment: Yes i tried that, it hides the bar. But what i want is to hide the bar and still be able to scroll. Thanks